# JAVA SWT KeyDown event triggered 3 times instead of one, when switching from SWT 3 to SWT 4

Tags: java, browser, swt, listener, keydown

The following issue has me puzzled : I have an SWT Java application and switching from SWT 3 to SWT 4 creates a strange behaviour of the KeyDown event in the following circumstances :

I have one shell containing a Browser widget. I am listening to KeyDown events at the Java level, via a filter on the Display object, as shown below. When such an event is detected, I then call the execute() function of the Browser widget in order to execute some javascript. I chose to detect the KeyDown event at the global java level and not directly in javascript because the browser may not necessarily have the focus at that moment.

Expected behaviour : the KeyDown event should be detected once

Actual behaviour : the KeyDown event is detected three times

What I tried and learned so far :
1) The problem only happens when the Browser widget is used.
2) The problem happens not only when executing some javascript, it also happens if I simply set the content of the browser (br.setText("...")), so it seems any action on the browser triggers the problem.
3) The problem doesn't happen with SWT 3.836. It happens with SWT 4.924

Reverting back to SWT 3 is not an ideal option, because it caused a lot of crashes due to libwebkitgtk, and I got rid of those with SWT 4...

Configuration : Ubuntu 18.04, Java openjdk 11 adm64, SWT 4.924 (downloaded from Eclipse download page latest stable version 4.14M1)

Here is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Launching test application");

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    Browser br = new Browser(shell,SWT.NONE);
    br.setSize(500,500);

    display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            System.out.println(event.keyCode);
            //Try either of the following two lines to reproduce the problem. If you comment both lines, the problem disappears
            br.execute("javascript:alert('hello')");
            //br.setText("<html><head></head><body>TEST</body></html>");
        }
    });

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
         {
            display.sleep();
         }
    }
}
```

Any hints ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: On macOS this code doesn't generate any key down events at all unless I initialize the browser with some contents - then it only gives 1 event plus a 'key stroke not accepted' beep.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on Windows 10 and SWT 4.924 and I'm getting the event 2 times.

My guess is that `Browser` is also interacting with the filter causing multiple events (see this old comment, not sure if related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=69919#c8).

Also it seems that the problem happens only when the `Browser` has the focus, and works correctly when some other control has the focus.

So, as a workaround, you might use the filter when the browser doesn't have the focus, otherwise a standard key listener on the `Browser` when it does.

For example:

```
br.addKeyListener(keyPressedAdapter(event -> {
    handleBrowserKeyEvent(br, event.keyCode);
}));

display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // when the browser has focus, use his key listener instead of this filter 
        if (br.isFocusControl()) {
            return;
        }
        handleBrowserKeyEvent(br, event.keyCode);
    }
});
```

Where in `handleBrowserKeyEvent` you put your handling logic.

Note that in my case I also had to put a `shell.forceFocus();` right after `shell.open();`, otherwise the browser key listener would not immediately work (I don't know why).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, on my Linux configuration, the KeyListener attached directly to the browser (br.addKeyListener) also fires the event 3 times. Interesting to see how some swt elements behave differently across platforms, where it's supposed to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty way of dealing with this would be to count the number of events and ingore 2 of them in every 3, like so :

```
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {

            if (i<2) {
                i++;
            }else {
                System.out.println(event.keyCode);
                i=0;
            }
        }
    });
```

`
However, for that to work I need to be 100% sure the event is systematically going to be called 3 times, which is the case at least in my simplified exemple and under my own configuration.

I think I'm going to use something like that in the meantime, but still it would be good to eventually get to the bottom of this.